# Problema para usar o gulp

Tags: node.js

Olha só, estou começando a usar o gulp comecei um projeto no meu computador de trabalho e tudo funcionou corretamente (Elementary OS).

Agora em casa o gulp não funciona bem (também Elementary OS).
Quando rodo o comando gulp, ele diz que não encontrou o gulpfile, embora ele esteja presente.
Se eu renomeio o gulpfile.js para Gulpfile.js o erro muda, aparecendo o seguinte:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/index.js:16
        throw new Error("No task named \"" + name + "\"");
              ^
Error: No task named "default"
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/index.js:16:15
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.module.exports.gulp.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/index.js:13:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp:17:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

Já reinstalei o node, o gulp e tudo mais, mas nada de funcionar.
o Node está na versão 0.10.25
o NPM está na versão 1.3.24

Comment: Acho que ajudaria incluir na questão: 1) A estrutura de diretório e o nome de todos os arquivos envolvidos; 2) Qual comando você está usando para invocar o Gulp e 3) O conteúdo do seu Gulpfile.

Comment: Acabei conseguindo resolver o problema. O nodejs que está no repositório do Elementary OS (baseado no ubuntu 12.04) é uma versão antiga, não compatível com o gulp. Daí eu tinha atualizado o node, usando o PPA oficial e, apesar disso, haviam configurações da versão antiga no sistema ainda, mesmo usando o purge. Daí eu removi as pastas do node que eu encontrei e reinstalei, agora o gulp funciona.

Comment: Luis Henrique: Você pode postar isso como resposta e aceitar depois de 24 horas. Assim você ajuda se alguém aparecer mais tarde como o mesmo problema.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, @missingno. Fiz isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabei conseguindo resolver o problema. O nodejs que está no repositório do Elementary OS (baseado no ubuntu 12.04) é uma versão antiga, não compatível com o gulp. Daí eu tinha atualizado o node, usando o PPA oficial e, apesar disso, haviam configurações da versão antiga no sistema ainda, mesmo usando o purge. Daí eu removi as pastas do node que encontrei e reinstalei, agora o gulp funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Certifique-se que no seu **gulpfile.js** há de fato a task **default**, como no exemplo abaixo:

```js
gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.run('scripts', 'styles', 'images', 'lr-server');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Faltou definir uma task com o nome default.

```
gulp.task('default', function() {
   /* cód aqui */
});
```

Comment: Não, não faltou. O problema é que eu não estava utilizando a versão correta do node, como apontado na resposta.